# Why is loading resnet50 keras model in TF 1.15 on TPU does not work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, tpu

I am trying to initialize resnet50 as backbone for a model in TF 1.15, and the model is run on google TPU V2. My code is this:

```
backbone_model=tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',pooling=None)
```

I get following errors.

```
<pre><code>


E1014 09:57:09.458413 140497105635136 tpu.py:425] Operation of type Placeholder (input_1) is not supported on the TPU. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph. 



   app.run(main)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/usman/nas/tpu.py", line 232, in main
    max_steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3035, in train
    rendezvous.raise_errors()
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/error_handling.py", line 136, in raise_errors
    six.reraise(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3030, in train
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1191, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2857, in _call_model_fn
    config)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1149, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3159, in _model_fn
    _train_on_tpu_system(ctx, model_fn_wrapper, dequeue_fn))
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3604, in _train_on_tpu_system
    device_assignment=ctx.device_assignment)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/tpu.py", line 1277, in split_compile_and_shard
    name=name)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/tpu.py", line 992, in split_compile_and_replicate
    outputs = computation(*computation_inputs)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3589, in multi_tpu_train_steps_on_single_shard
    inputs=[0, _INITIAL_LOSS])
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/training_loop.py", line 178, in while_loop
    condition_wrapper, body_wrapper, inputs, name="", parallel_iterations=1)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2753, in while_loop
    return_same_structure)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2245, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2170, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/tpu/training_loop.py", line 121, in body_wrapper
    outputs = body(*(inputs + dequeue_ops))
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 3588, in <lambda>
    lambda i, loss: [i + 1, single_tpu_train_step(i)],
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 1715, in train_step
    self._call_model_fn(features, labels))
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 1994, in _call_model_fn
    estimator_spec = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/nas/tpu.py", line 120, in model
    pooling=None)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return base_fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/applications/resnet.py", line 33, in ResNet50
    return resnet.ResNet50(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_applications/resnet_common.py", line 435, in ResNet50
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_applications/resnet_common.py", line 411, in ResNet
    model.load_weights(weights_path)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 182, in load_weights
    return super(Model, self).load_weights(filepath, by_name)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1373, in load_weights
    saving.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 693, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3259, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 486, in get_session
    _initialize_variables(session)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 903, in _initialize_variables
    [variables_module.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in candidate_vars])
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1165, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 488, in __init__
    self._assert_fetchable(graph, fetch.op)
  File "/home/usman/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 505, in _assert_fetchable
    % op.name)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InaccessibleTensorError: Operation 'VarIsInitializedOp' has been marked as not fetchable. Typically this happens when it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values,explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.

</code></pre>
```

From what I have searched , following is the closest guess to the error I am getting ,  it is not possible to fetch the result of an op created inside the while loop's body, because the body might execute 0 or more times, based on the loop condition. To get a value out of the loop, you need to return it from the body function (as one of the loop variables), and its final value after all the iterations will be returned from tf.while_loop(). But this happens inside tf code , not externally , because i am only running a single line code for initialization of a model.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Yes , I edited it

Comment: Here is a list of available TensorFlow ops: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tensorflow-ops on Cloud TPU

Comment: yes , I checked the error op is available as a graph op on TPU.